# Do donated clan war troops spawn on both attacks?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In Clash of Clan, we can donate troops to clan members' castles during the preparation day for a clan war. Enemies can attack each base twice. Do these troops spawn to defend during both attacks, or just for the first one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The troops in the clan castle indeed defend *each* attack.

You can be attacked more than two times in a war, but your clan castle is always full for defending against those attacks, full of whatever was in the castle at the end of the war's preparation phase.

Additionally in war:

1. Heroes are always active to defend your War village.
2. Defenses like Xbows and Inferno towers, and traps are preloaded
3. Any defenses *under construction* are active in war, unlike your home village. In fact, any defense **STARTED** prior to the end of preparation day is active and defends your war village.

Comment: also - your traps will be fully loaded, even if they weren't loaded at all at the beginning of the war :-)